# How to send File Object to Web api using POST call in Xamarin forms.?

Tags: c#, file, post, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

I need to make a POST call from my Xamarin forms app where I need to upload a file object as it is to API using POST Call. Is there any way to make it possible?

Answer (score 1):

if you send file object using Base64 or Byte[] then it will allowed only limited may be upto 2-4 Mb but if you have a larger image than that it will not support.

So, **Solution** is Post Stream Content Like,

```
var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new PickMediaOptions
            {
                PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Full,
                CompressionQuality = 100
            });
```

Create Object of **MediaFile** like, `public MediaFile AttachedImage;` and Store file into it so Memory stream will not lost. Like,`AttachedImage = file`

Post Code on API,

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
MultipartFormDataContent mt = new MultipartFormDataContent();
AttachedImage.GetStream().Position = 0;
StreamContent imagePart = new StreamContent(AttachedImage.GetStream());
imagePart.Headers.Add("Content-Type", ImageType);
mt.Add(imagePart, String.Format("file"), String.Format("bk.jpeg"));

requestMessage.Content = mt;


var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("Your URL", mt);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var objRootObjectuploadImage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObjectuploadImage>(responseString);
    if (objRootObjectuploadImage != null)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
else
{
    Loading(ActIndicator, false);
    await DisplayAlert(res.LAlert, "webserver not responding.", res.LOk);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

NO, it is not possible to send file object. You can send as a json by converting the file in the Base64 string. This is the advised proven solution. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919387/converting-file-into-base64string-and-back-again) has code for converting back and forth from Base64.